# How to access the unresolved entities in lxml and Python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a well formed XML with code like this:

```
    <fxp-connector name="streaming" host="&fxvmnsrv.host;" port="&fxvmnsrv.port;" mode="INITIATOR">
        <message type="1" .../>
       ....
    </fxp-connector>
    .....
```

I am parsing it with:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
parser = ET.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False)
tree = ET.parse(inCfgFileName, parser)
....
outFile = open(outCfgFileName, "w")
......
e = tree.findall('fxp-connector[@name="streaming"]')
.....
tree.write(outFile)
```

In the output that line becomes:

```
&fxvmnsrv.host;&fxvmnsrv.port;<fxp-connector name="streaming" host="" port="" mode="INITIATOR">
```

...

`print e[0]` prints the `<message .../>` tag
How do I get access to those entity references? I tried a few things, but no luck so far.

Comment: what did you try, what is outFile, please show some code

Comment: Dmitry, I updated the question with the sample of the code

Answer (score 0):

Found them. They are inserted into the root, i.e. on the same level as `<fxp-connector>` right in front of it.

```
for i in range(20):
print i, root[i]
```

produces:

```
9 &fxvmnsrv.host;
10 &fxvmnsrv.port;
11 <Element fxp-connector at 0xffffffff7b7386c8> #this is the <fxp-connector tag>
```